# spark_ec2 error when launching (present file is not found)

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I want to launch a spark cluster on EC2 using the following command line:

```
python spark_ec2.py --key-pair=alexistest2 --identity-file=C:\User\Alexis\Downloads\alexistest2.pem --region=us-west-2 --instance-type=t2.medium --spark-version=1.2.0 launch my-spark-cluster
```

After I get "Waiting for all instances in cluster to enter 'ssh-ready' state", the following error happens.

```
Waiting for all instances in cluster to enter 'ssh-ready' state.Traceback (most
recent call last):
  File "spark_ec2.py", line 1083, in <module>
    main()
  File "spark_ec2.py", line 1075, in main
    real_main()
  File "spark_ec2.py", line 931, in real_main
    opts=opts
  File "spark_ec2.py", line 640, in wait_for_cluster_state
    is_cluster_ssh_available(cluster_instances, opts):
  File "spark_ec2.py", line 611, in is_cluster_ssh_available
    if not is_ssh_available(host=i.ip_address, opts=opts):
  File "spark_ec2.py", line 602, in is_ssh_available
    stderr=devnull
  File "C:\Users\Alexis\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 535, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alexis\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Users\Alexis\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Users\Alexis\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child

    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've checked my Python folder and the subprocess.py file is present in "C:\Users\Alexis\Anaconda\Lib".

I have edited spark_ec2 in order to [add UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null](https://github.com/grzegorz-dubicki/spark/commit/5dd8458d2ab9753aae939b3bb33be953e2c13a70?diff=split).

Still, I get the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with your path, you wrote "C:/User" and perhaps it should be "C:/Users".

Answer (score 0):

it might be problem with case-sensitive?

the script is looking for "C:\Users\Alexis\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py"

and you have it in "C:\Users\Alexis\Anaconda\Lib\subprocess.py".

try changing the dir name to "lib" instead of "Lib"

Comment: I had noticed that and did change the dir name, but unfortunately that's not the problem.

Comment: could this be an environment variables issue? My PATH variable looks like this: "C:\Users\Alexis\Anaconda;C:\Users\Alexis\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Users\Alexis\Anaconda\lib;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin;%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Java\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;"

Comment: what about permisions for running that script? what version of python do you have? the /lib is on your path so it should be an issue with that